# Syntax error when trying to import CSV with Hash symbol

Tags: node.js, csv

I am trying to import a .csv file but getting an error due to the fact that it uses hash symbols.  This is my code:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const { parse } = require("csv-parse");
const filePath = require("./configs/note_freq_440_432.csv");

fs.createReadStream(filePath, { encoding: "utf8" })
  .pipe(parse({ delimiter: ",", from_line: 2 }))
  .on("data", (row) => {
    console.log(row);
  })
  .on("end", function () {
    console.log("finished");
  })
  .on("error", function (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  });
```

I am receiving this error:

```
22,A#,0,29.1353,28.61
    ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Due to this line in the .csv file:

```
22,A#,0,29.1353,28.61
```

I've tried various different configurations for the `options` object for `fs.createReadStream` with no luck.  How can I successfully parse this .csv with '#' characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use require csv `const filePath = require("./configs/note_freq_440_432.csv");`,the require is commonly used to import Js or JSON files. When you try to import a CSV file Node.js tries to parse it as JS.

so, update your code like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const csvParse = require('csv-parse');
const path = require('path');

const filePath = path.join(__dirname, './432.csv'); // file path

fs.createReadStream(filePath, { encoding: 'utf8' })
.pipe(csvParse.parse({ delimiter: ',', from_line: 2 }))
.on('data', (row) => {
  console.log(row);
})
.on('end', function () {
  console.log('Finished');
})
.on('error', function (error) {
  console.log('Error:', error.message);
});
```